# Display two values in textbox

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm trying to display two values in a textbox but the value should be next line. here is my sample query. here i tried 
 also its not working. give me a idea to display in a next line.... thank you..

```
</head>
<?php 
$s='hi';
?>
</br>
<?php
$d='how are you';
?>
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <label>
  <input type="text" name="textfield" value="<?php echo $s."<br />"; echo $d?>" id="textfield" />
  </label>
</form>
```

Comment: Use textarea instead of input box

Comment: why do you answer in a comment? answer <> comment...

Answer (score 3):

Use a textarea, and line breaks instead of `<br>` elements.

```
 <textarea name="textfield"><?php echo $s."\n".$d; ?></textarea>
```

to output the contents of the textarea in a HTML document with proper line breaks, use [`nl2br()`](http://www.php.net/nl2br).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot display line breaks in textfields (input type="text"). You will need a  `<textarea>` for that.

Use <textarea><?php echo $s."\n".$d; ?></textarea>

Comment: Because textbox is designed to hold single-line text only :) You cann't change/configure it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
<textarea><?php echo $s."\n"; echo $d?></textarea>
```

instead of

```
<input type="text"
```

because textbox supports only single-line text

Comment: ok thx distdev... can we use textarea like textbox.. if i want to change the value,backround color etc...

Comment: You can do it as for usual textbox